# How we add tabs in plugin page

Tags: plugins, tabs

I want to add tabs in my test-plugin. I have add a folder '3 test plugin' with file '3 test-plugin.php'. I have activate plugin and add in the setting admin menu. Please give the details of adding tabs in my plugin file. thanks in advance. file code is follow:

### Hello World Options

Enter Text
                    
                        " />
                        (ex. Hello World)

" />

Comment: where you want to add the tabs?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to add tabs in admin page then you can try doing this:

```
<h3 class="nav-tab-wrapper">     
  <a class="nav-tab nav-tab-active" href="#">Test1</a>
  <a class="nav-tab" href="#">Test2</a>
  <a class="nav-tab" href="#">Test3</a>
  <a class="nav-tab" href="#">Test4</a>
  <a class="nav-tab" href="#">Test5</a>
  <a class="nav-tab" href="#">Test6</a>
</h3>
```

this will give you native look and feel